# In Swift, how do I permanently change the text of a label of a within a different ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

In one of my ViewControllers, called SecondViewController, I have the following code, which allows me to change a string variable within another ViewController, called ThirdViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : ThirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController

    if (DestViewController.order1Text == "" ) {
    DestViewController.order1Text = " \(pizzaSize) \(crustSelected) crust pizza, sauce on \(sauceChoice) pizza"
    } else {
    DestViewController.order2Text = " \(pizzaSize) \(crustSelected) crust pizza, sauce on \(sauceChoice) pizza"
    }
}
```

The ThirdViewController, contains the following code, and although the "order1Label" label changes successfully (since it is tied to the string variable) in when the Segue takes me to the ThirdViewController, the text in that label disappears when I leave the ThirdViewController and move to a different ViewController. How do I make the text stay in the label that I am controlling from an outside ViewController?

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

var order1Text = String()
var order2Text = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    order1Label.text = order1Text
    order2Label.text = order2Text
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBOutlet weak var order1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var order2Label: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: change the code from viewDidLoad to viewwillapper and check oncec

Answer (score -1):

Make your IBOutlet strong property as like below

```
@IBOutlet strong var order1Label: UILabel!
```

**Reason**

A strong reference (which you will use in most cases) means that you want to "own" the object you are referencing with this property/variable. The compiler will take care that any object that you assign to this property will not be destroyed as long as you point to it with a strong reference. Only once you set the property to nil will the object get destroyed (unless one or more other objects also hold a strong reference to it).

In contrast, with a weak reference you signify that you don't want to have control over the object's lifetime. The object you are referencing weakly only lives on because at least one other object holds a strong reference to it. Once that is no longer the case, the object gets destroyed and your weak property will automatically get set to nil. The most frequent use cases of weak references in iOS are:

1. delegate properties, which are often referenced weakly to avoid retain cycles, and
2. subviews/controls of a view controller's main view because those views are already strongly held by the main view.

Comment: I tried using viewwillappear function and making the outlet strong, and neither helped me preserve the data once I left the ThirdViewController. Once I leave ThirdViewController and come back, the text in order1Label is gone. Any ideas why? 

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        order1Label.text = order1Text
        order2Label.text = order2Text
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var order1Label: UILabel!

Comment: @shampouya call super of .`viewWillAppear` like this `super.viewwillappear(true)`. Can you explain either you pop this `thirdVC` or pushing other VC ? I mean from 3rdVC either you go back and come or go forward and come to back to 3rdVC?